# Installing Umbraco 4.7

Tags: umbraco

I am new to Umbraco and i have heard lot good about this cms.

I want to start Umbraco, but here are newbie questions.

1. How to Install Umbraco on my local machine.
2. Ones I make Umbraco work according to my need, what are requirement for deploying on Shared Hosting.
3. How to deploy on Shared Hosting Server.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Go for Webmatrix - Umbraco setup 30 sec.! [www.asp.net/webmatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to question 2. Yuo will need the dot net framework installed (4.0) - some hosts say it is but I have known at least one where the avertising blurb did not match the actual enviroment. You also need SQLExpress (2008 R2 is you best version). Once these are up and running, its the same as any database & iis app.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I found useful, is that Umbraco also provides a WebDeploy (http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) package that makes it very easy to deploy on IIS:http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/73692 look for 'Umbraco_4.7.1_WebDeploy_NET_4.0'.

I do the initial deployment on my development machine, the release to production could be as simple as a copy and paste (plus the db-release).

Hope this helps,

-covo

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco ships in two type of packages.

1. Zip Package
2. Nuget Package

**1) Zip Package**

Zip package contains an Asp.Net website with Umbraco pre-installed in it. All you have to do is to extract the package inside a local directory, host the directory in IIS as a website and open in browser. Umbraco will guide you through the configuration steps, you can also install a starter kit that is a sample website template and is pretty fancy. Umbraco ships three starter kits along with installation package you can chose the one of your choice.

Step 1:

Navigate to umbraco download url and hit “Download Umbraco version*”: https://our.umbraco.org/download/

You’ll get a zip package of nearly 20MB size.

Step 2:

Extract the zip package into a folder and put that folder on any of your computer’s drive.

Step 3:

Open IIS Manager, add new website and point it to your Umbraco folder and start the website.

Step 4:

Now, browse this website, you’ll see the configuration page would appear, enter your name, email and password for Umbraco dashboard, remember your email id would be used as a user name for logging in dashboard. You can see you have two buttons; Install and Customize, Clicking install would get you the standard features in which you get “.sdf” database file inside your project’s “App_Data” folder. Customize on the other hand provides us with many handy configuration options. We’ll follow the customize route to get good understanding of the process.

Step 5:

When going for customized installation, you’ll see the database configuration options. Configure them according to your choice, Note that you’d have to specify a Database server and database name, you can create a new database on your server and you can use an existing database as well. Alternatively, you can select the SQL Server Compact Edition option from dropdown which would create “.sdf” database inside your project.

Step 6:

The next step in configuration would allow you to install a starter kit, starter kits are built in website templates. Let’s just select one of them for sake of learning although you won’t be needing them once you’d be well versed with the components in Umbraco Dashboard. Click on any of the three starter kits and let Umbraco do the magic.

It would take a couple of minutes and then you’ll be redirected to dashboard of your brand new website powered by Umbraco. Welcome to the Umbraco World. You can navigate to the installed website by removing Umbraco from URL. In our case http://localhost/ would show you the website

and http://localhost/umbraco would take you to the dashboard.

**2) Nuget Package**

Umbraco is also available in Nuget Package Repository. Follow the steps to install Umbraco using Nuget.

Step 1:

Create an Asp.Net or Asp.Net MVC Project in visual studio.

Step 2:

Open Package Manager Console and run the following command: “Install-Package UmbracoCms"

Umbraco will start installing inside your web application. Alternatively, you can right click on your project, hit Manage Nuget packages, find Umbraco CMS there and install it. There’s a slight possibility that your installation fails with error, normally updating the Nuget version solves the problem. Once the Umbraco is installed inside your project you can either run it by hitting F5/ Play from visual studio or you can host a website in IIS like we did in Umbraco installation from a ZIP package.

Step 3:

Once you've managed to browse your web application project in browser, All the next steps are same as ZIP package installation, specify login credentials, configure database and starter kits and Bingo! Umbraco’s installed.